# Joining sql table with multiple group concats

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following tables:

- movies: (id, title)
- actor: (id, name)
- director: (id, name)
- movies_actors: (movie_id, actor_id)
- movies_directors: (movie_id, director_id)

The last two tables represent the relationships between the movies and the actors and directors. I want to retrieve a list of movies including it's actors and directors, comma seperated.

I've tried the following to retrieve this information, for ex:

```
SELECT movie.title,
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT name FROM actors WHERE id=movies_actors.actor) SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'actors',
GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT name FROM directors WHERE id=movies_directors.director) SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'directors'
FROM movies
LEFT JOIN movies_actors ON movies_actors.movie = movies.id
LEFT JOIN movies_directors ON movies_directors.movie = movies.id
```

However, this returns the result as follows:

| title | actors | directors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| movieTitle | actorA, actorB, actorC | directorA, directorA, directorA |

Even though the movie only has one director, it is displayed 3 times. I would like to have the result as follows:

| title | actors | directors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| movieTitle | actorA, actorB, actorC | directorA |

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is subqueries.  You can use correlated subqueries for this purpose:

```
SELECT m.title,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.name, SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM movies_actors ma JOIN
             actors a
             ON a.id = ma.actor
        WHERE ma.movie = m.id
       ) AS actors,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(d.name, SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM movies_directors md JOIN
             directors d
             ON d.id = md.director
        WHERE md.movie = m.id
       ) AS directors
FROM movies m;
```

Note what is happening here.  For each movie, each subquery is gathering all the rows of interest and combining the names into a single column.  No aggregation is needed in the outer query, because each subquery returns exactly one row.

When you join on the junction tables in the outer query, you are getting a Cartesian product of actors and directors for each movie -- and that throws off the results.